# sort giving strange results

Tags: php

I have an array of email addresses that I am trying to sort, but I'm getting odd results.  Here is what I mean:

```
sort($array);
print_r($array);
...[79] => 91******@******.com [80] => 9l***@**********.com 
[81] => ps*******@**********.com [82] => a.c******@*****.com 
[83] => a.d****@*****.com...
```

What would cause that email beginning with p's to be mixed in after the numbers and before the A's?

I removed that email address from the database and replaced it with "testing" and then "testing" appeared in the same position.

Comment: Perhaps there is a leading space before the `p`?

Comment: `var_dump($array);`

Comment: Can you paste tho whole code (how do you get data from db), it has to be something with the database...

Comment: maybe if you showed us more code or the list you are trying to sort. Im having a problem with sorting in php as well you can look at my question to see it. Its a different sort but maybe there is some common problems?

Comment: var_dump($array); returns:  ...[81]=> string(126) "ps******@*****.com" [82]=> string(20) "a.c*****@*****.com"...

Comment: as i told you in my answer (and @Cthulhu too) ... you have a space before ps. inspecting your post you can see it - `<span class="pln"> ps</span>`

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you're comparing in English put this before your sort:

```
  setlocale (LC_COLLATE, 'en_US');
  sort($array);
```

If this changes anything and the sort works, your system is set to compare strings not as US/English.

Other than that, I can only think of spaces being at the start of the string or some starting with upper case and others starting lower.  To fix cased string sorting issues, you could do:

```
  natsort($array);
```

Comment: actually you can have a limited kind of chars in the email. yes it is possible to have a mistake when entering email, but inspecting the code shows that the `ps` consists of latin chars.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space before `ps` ... when I inspected the code you posted it is visible. Make a `trim` before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are sorting with some weird rule. Force the sorting mode to "string" passing SORT_STRING

```
sort($array, SORT_STRING);
```

and tell us what it spit out.

sort() uses SORT_REGULAR as default, I suspect that the emails with numeric prefixes (92*) are considered integers thus the weird sorting.